# Custom Field Create Bulk via SQL Query

Tags: custom-field, query, sql, bulk

I have a question.  A created a custom field named video_desc. I have ofer 2000 posts and I need to add this custom field to all posts and add the text "Description Here"  to it. How can this be done with SQL Query because all plugins I used didn't worked as it should. 
TThanks!

Answer (score 1):

I manage to work my problem.
For those who seek the same answer, just run this query

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT wp_posts.ID, 'video_desc', 'Description here'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish';
```